# NServiceBus : When using 2 subscribers, 2 messages end up in both queues

Tags: nservicebus

I'm new to using NServiceBus, so I'm pretty sure I'm just screwing up the configuration of my pub/sub functionality...

I've got 2 subscribers ( A & B ) set up to handle the same event. I'm using MSMQ for message storage. If I comment the handler for B and only subscribe A then the handler for A is called only once (and only 1 message is in the Queue for A).

However, when I uncomment the handler in the B subscriber to handling the same event. BOTH A & B get two of the same exact message in their Queues, which results each handler getting run twice.

I'm using NServiceBus 3.2.0.0, each of the event subscribers are in separate project and running in their own NServiceBus Hosts.

Here's my setup of the Bus...

```
    private IBus CreateBus()
    {
        return Configure.With()
            .NinjectBuilder(this.Kernel)
            .Log4Net()
            .MsmqTransport()
            .PurgeOnStartup(true)
            .UnicastBus()
            .LoadMessageHandlers()
            .CreateBus()
            .Start(() => Configure.Instance.ForInstallationOn<NServiceBus.Installation.Environments.Windows>().Install());
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ninject has had issues with NServiceBus before: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/message/6253 not sure if still related. Perhaps try another object builder provider.

Comment: Please provide the configuration of your publisher as well.

Comment: My guess is that you have both handlers in each Subscriber, is that true?

Comment: It turns out to be a misuse of ninject. I am also utilizing an EventStore in my solution, so when I was injecting a second EventStore instance before the first instance finished committing something, it republished the uncommitted first event.

Comment: Can you put this as the answer so we can close this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be a misuse of ninject. I am also utilizing an EventStore in my solution, so when I was injecting a second EventStore instance before the first instance finished committing something, it republished the uncommitted first event.